# Update camera initialCameraPosition pressed by button

Tags: flutter, gps

After a long time i still tried to update position of camera by coordinates i arrived at this point

```
   Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition:
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,
          currentLocation.longitude), zoom: 17),
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      mapType: _currentMapType,
      markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),

    )
```

And all work ok but ...at start map center in position from gps ... when i try to update cameraposition by button

```
static final CameraPosition _position1 = CameraPosition(
bearing: 192.833,
target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,currentLocation.longitude),
tilt: 59.440,
zoom: 11.0,
```

);

Recive an error in target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,currentLocation.longitude),
say: "only static member can be accessed in initializer 
so i can't update cameraposition to new gps position... someone know how to fix... can i create a stream of data? To track location ?

Answer (score 0):

I thin you just need to change your code as follow and try

```
final CameraPosition _position1 = CameraPosition(
bearing: 192.833,
target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,currentLocation.longitude),
tilt: 59.440,
zoom: 11.0,
);
```